# How to import mysql dump file but avoid resetting primary keys and keep them as they were before

Tags: mysql

I've made a mysql dump file using a "DataGrip" 2020 version. When I want to import a mysql dump file to restore the database tables and rows, it ignores "ids" and reset them from the beginning.

Given a database A have the most recent row with an ID 125, while in reality there are 86 rows.

When I export all rows into a sql file and try to import them into a database B, the most recent row is no longer 125, but 86 instead.

Is there a way to skip or ignore resetting an "ID" auto_increment parameter while importing a sql file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, there is no problem.

How are you doing the dump?  Using `mysqldump` should not lose ID 125.  Since the output of the dump is a readable, look at it.  You will see it re-inserting 125.  (And leaving the gaps that the table currently has.)

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right, I really had to use a command line for `mysqldump` and avoid using DataGrip tool, as I didn't found any options there. Thank you for confirming about leaving gaps with `mysqldump`.